# Parse Excel using HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, directory, local

I want to parse excel file using javascript in html. I successfully parsed it by reading . But i want it automatically read the excel from current directory on page load. is it possible? Because i want to run the html in as local file without any server.

Comment: Did you try to use SheetJS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

you will simply specify in the init according to docs appropriate file you want to open and then it is easy as follow docs

Comment: but it says cors blocked while reading it from local: 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://..../excel.xlsx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @BibinKJ try `chmod -R 777 /path/to/file`, if that wont solve your problem you will need to  make a simple php server `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: @BibinKJ the thing is, you cant do this type of stuff in modern browser without at least simple php server